# Fetching Relationships in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am interested to fetch relationships from neo4j. Basically, after retrieving some relationships, it looks like below as json:

```
{
    "r": {
      "_nodeNeo4j": {
        "version": "1.1.1",
        "constructor": "Relationship"
      },
      "_data": {
        "extensions": {},
        "start": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1",
        "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/65",
        "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/65/properties/{key}",
        "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/65/properties",
        "type": "FOLLOWS",
        "end": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/79",
        "metadata": {
          "id": 65,
          "type": "FOLLOWS"
        },
        "data": {}
      }
    }
  }
```

However, I am interested to retrieve only few attributes instead of all.

1) How can I retrieve only partial  data please?

2) Also, does creation have any timestamp for itself or should I have to set external attributes to track the time a relationship is created?

Comment: What driver do you use?

Comment: If you are only interested in a few properties, then write a Cypher statement that only returns the properties you want.